# Since when can't I jump to pages in Google Books?

Tags: google-books

While browsing Google Books I noticed I can't access individual sites anymore, i.e. also no table of contents or anything. I mean I see the page number there, but I can't do anything about it!

Is it only me / my browser or maybe the publisher's books? Why is Google doing this?

This severely hampers the whole reason to use this offer, as it is already only a workaround and emergency solution for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The availability of preview varies from publisher to publisher, from book to book. This is **not** a Google or your individual issue. 
If a book belongs to a publisher and not public domain then Google (and users) are at the mercy of publishers. That is why for some books you have preview and for some you don't.

More info: http://books.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=43729&topic=9259&hl=en

To confirm check the following (you should see the text of the book for this one): http://books.google.com/books?id=g_NLGFK9qZMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb